# Start timer with mention time and date using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I have been trying to get the timer set with the mention date and time. 
Below is the code i tried so far.

```js
function timer() {
  var now = new Date();
  var outStr = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById('clockDiv').innerHTML = outStr;
  setTimeout('timer()', 1000);
}
timer();
```

```html
<html>
  <head><title></title></head>
  <body onload="timer();">
    <div id="clockDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above code gives the output of system date but i want to specify the date and the timer should start from that day itself.

Example: I tried adding date and time in the new date() as below:

```
var now = new Date('Wed, 15 May 2013 13:05:32');
```

But then the timer doesn't work.

Could someone please help me out here?

Comment: It sounds like you want to schedule a job to run on fixed schedule. Its better to do it on the backend/server side. What technologies you are using on backend?

Comment: @gt_ebuddy are right. I want only add that your Date format in constructor's wrong? Look there:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Comment: You didn't answered my question : What technologies you are using on backend?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this codepen](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MwNPVq) I made this:

```js
function getTimeRemaining() {
  var t = Date.parse('Wed, 15 May 2013 13:05:32') - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}



function display(){
  var t = getTimeRemaining();
  document.write(-t.days + " days, " + -t.hours + " hours, " + -t.minutes + " minutes, " + -t.seconds + " seconds since " + 'Wed, 15 May 2013 13:05:32' + '<br>');
}
var timeinterval = setInterval(display, 1000);
```

The date and the negative to positive results are pretty much hard-coded, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thnks for sharing this. But i want my timer to get start from that mentioned time and forever. There is no end time count.